# Switch out view controller before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

I am making (yet another) photo app, and I have a question on how to create the following workflow:

Upon opening app, you are shown the welcome screen (A). In this screen I have a button that I want to open the camera.

When photo is taken and you are closing the modal camera view controller,  I want to show another control "underneath" the `UIImagePickerController` (let's call this view controller (B)).

Somehow I want to switch out view controller A with view controller B when `UIImagePickerController` calls `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

Is this possible, if not, what is the best practice for doing this?